# Merge or override xml variable using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, merge, simplexml

I have 2 xml files
file1:

```
<xml_file>
    <var1>Value 1</var1>
    <var2>Value 2</var2>
    <var3>Value 3</var3>
</xml_file>
```

file2:

```
<xml_file>
    <var3>New value 3</var3>
</xml_file>
```

I load file1 using `$xml = simplexml_load_file("path/file1.xml");`
And what I'd love to achieve is to also load file2 and override var3 with the value in this new file (New value 3).

I managed to do it using this solution, but i was wondering if there is another one easier and maybe faster:

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file("path/file1.xml");
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("path/file2.xml");
$xml = (object)array_merge((array)$xml1, (array)$xml2);
```

Thanks for your ideas ;)

Comment: What you have is 3 lines of code. How much easier are you expecting?

Comment: haha :) you're right but i was meaning a better solution, that uses less resources...

Comment: replace values just one level below root or any level?

Comment: I'll always have ONLY ONE level

Answer (score 0):

The xml content you presented from `file1` isn't valid. Opening and closing tags must coincide:

```
<xml_file>
    <var1>Value 1</var1>
    <var2>Value 2</var2>
    <var3>Value 3</var3>
</xml_file>
```

To override `var3` node value in first xml with respective node value from the second xml you can simply assign the value of one node to another.

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file("path/file1.xml");
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("path/file2.xml");
$xml1->var3 = $xml2->var3;

var_dump($xml1->asXML());
// the output:
string '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml_file>
    <var1>Value 1</var1>
    <var2>Value 2</var2>
    <var3>New value 3</var3>

</xml_file>
' (length=124)
```

---

**UPDATE**
An additional approach for multiple node values replacements. It uses `array_intersect_key` function which returns an array containing all the entries of `$xml2` which have keys that are present in `$xml1`:

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_string('<xml_file>
    <var1>Value 1</var1>
    <var2>Value 2</var2>
    <var3>Value 3</var3>
    <var4>Value 4</var4>
    <var5>Value 4</var5>
</xml_file>');

$xml2 = simplexml_load_string('<xml_file>
    <var3>New value 3</var3>
    <var5>New Value 5</var5>
</xml_file>');

$matches = array_intersect_key((array)$xml2, (array) $xml1);
foreach ($matches as $node_name => $v) {
   $xml1->$node_name = $v;   // $v is a node value from $xml2
}
var_dump($xml1->asXML());
// the output:
string '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml_file>
    <var1>Value 1</var1>
    <var2>Value 2</var2>
    <var3>New value 3</var3>
    <var4>Value 4</var4>
    <var5>New Value 5</var5>
</xml_file>
' (length=178)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Comment: Hi Roman, sorry about the closing tags, it was just a mistake, i should blame the copy/paste :D
In the example, i gave an example of overriding var3, but it couldn't be any variable among few hundreds I have in the xml file! so i can't use the assign solution :/

Comment: please elaborate, by what conditions should be done those replacements. In your question only `var3` node was intended. What is the full condition?

Comment: every variable in file2 also exists in file1. So should any variable be in file2, it must replace the one in file1

Comment: @Websphere, check my additional approach

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, now I have to chose between my solution, yours and michi's :/ which is a little hard :D

Comment: Hi again, I ended up using Roman's solution :) I have another little question pls: i sometimes have to convert  the variable as follow `echo (string) $xml->var4;` but i was wondering if there a way to convert all of the variable at once to prevent converting them individually... Thanks

Comment: hello, to get an array of node values as an array of strings use this: `$arr = (array) $xml; $new_arr = explode(',', implode(",", $arr));`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the fast reply :) Actually i don't use arrays, i would like to keep using `$xml->var4`

Comment: Don't worry about that. In your case, you don't need convert node value to string, it's already a string. Even if one of the nodes would be as this `<var3>3</var3>`, the `var3` node has a string value `3` anyway

Comment: OK, but what i don't understand is `$new_arr`, what would I do with it as i need the change the be affected to $xml ?

Comment: you can not affect value types in a live xml structure. Change values - yes, change type - no

Comment: oh, that's a problem then, that means i have to change the way I echo variable in all the website??!! :/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over every variable in `$xml2` and use `xpath` to select and replace it in `$xml1`:

```
foreach ($xml2->children() as $name => $value) {
    foreach ($xml1->xpath("//$name") as $replace) 
        $replace[0] = $value;
}
```

see it working: https://eval.in/522121

Note: `$xml2` is only one level deep. If there are children of children, a recursive approach is necessary.

Comment: thanks michi for your your script. I'll try it out and will let you know ;)
so just fo my info, why is your solution better than the array_merge() ?? :)

Comment: @Websphere this is for you to find out :)